# inheritance in structs prototypes

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++98

Is it possible to represent this in C++:

```cpp
struct foo {
    int x;
    int y;
    struct A derived;
};

struct A {
    int val;
};

struct B : A {
    int baz[10];
};

struct C : A {
    int baz[20];
};
```

Where `derived` can be any of the inherited structs of A (either B or C) but never A, without changing the prototype `struct foo`?
For example is it be possible to do the to do the following?

```cpp
void func(void)
{
    struct B b;
    struct foo foo;
    foo.derived = b;
}
```

Comment: derived will always be an A. Not a B, not a C. If you want polymorphism derived should be a pointer/reference to A.

Comment: If it can never be A, then why provide A at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct A {
    int val;
    virtual ~A() = 0; // so nobody can instantiate A alone.
};
inline
A::~A() = default; // the destructor HAS to be defined.

struct foo {
    int x;
    int y;
    std::unique_ptr<A> derived;
};
```

And then the rest being the same...and using:

```
foo foo_v;  foo_v.derived = std::make_unique<B>();
```

Note that I've eliminated the C language elements and made it pure C++.  I'd also clean these up and make them more cohesive.  Does it make sense that x and y are uninitialized in the above code?  Probably not, so there should be a constructor that forces them to be provided, sets them to an initial value, or both.